# PayPal IPN Status

Tags: paypal

i am working on PayPal IPN and got problem when i got payment status = reversed.

is it possible for Paypal to send status = reversed for first time  hit to IPN?

Shouldn't i got the status = completed first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its an eCheck, then it could be reversed before the check was completed... You don't get the money for those until PayPal clears the ACH.

Comment: just know about that. thanks for your info. where can i find the reference?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, other than the PayPal API... I've had to deal with IPN stuff at work..